# Weird Ansible issue

Tags: ansible

When I use two consecutive shell tasks with When condition "when: ansible_distribution == 'Amazon' and when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'" its fails to register variable(attributes) of first tasks
If I disable task with "when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'" it works perfectly.
here I am using local Centos VM but this is true for CentOS EC2 instance.

Playbook

```
- hosts: "{{ target }}"

  tasks:

    - name: uptime al2
      shell: uname -r
      changed_when: true
      ignore_errors: true
      register: ucheck
      when: ansible_distribution == 'Amazon'


    - name: uptime centos
      shell: uname -r
      changed_when: true
      ignore_errors: true
      register: ucheck
      when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat'

    - debug:
        msg: "RC is {{ ucheck.rc }}"
```

**Running on CentOS**

```
[root@server1 ~]# ansible-playbook -i localhost, vagrant-ansible/playbooks/al2-test.yml -e target=localhost

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [uptime al2] ********************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [uptime centos] *****************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "RC is 0"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Runing on AL2**

```
[root@server1 ~]# ansible-playbook -i 3.238.194.98, vagrant-ansible/playbooks/al2-test.yml -e target=3.238.194.98 -u ec2-user --private-key=<keypair>

PLAY [3.238.194.98] ******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host 3.238.194.98 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation
of another Python interpreter could change this. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [3.238.194.98]

TASK [uptime al2] ********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [3.238.194.98]

TASK [uptime centos] *****************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [3.238.194.98]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [3.238.194.98]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/vagrant-ansible/playbooks/al2-test.yml': line 20, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
3.238.194.98               : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Runing after disabling Second Task**

```
[root@server1 ~]# ansible-playbook -i 3.238.194.98, vagrant-ansible/playbooks/al2-test.yml -e target=3.238.194.98 -u ec2-user --private-key=<keypair>

PLAY [3.238.194.98] ******************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host 3.238.194.98 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation
of another Python interpreter could change this. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
ok: [3.238.194.98]

TASK [uptime al2] ********************************************************************************************************************
changed: [3.238.194.98]

TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [3.238.194.98] => {
    "msg": "RC is 0"
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************
3.238.194.98               : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: You probably need a `not` condition for this to work, e.g. `and not ansible_distribution == 'CentOS'`, but that is only if I understood your question. :)

Comment: ansible_distribution is centos, ansible_os_family is redhat.

Comment: Any when clause will not change the fact that a skipped task will be registered as skipped and won't contain an `rc` attribute. See answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue and is absolutely expected. `register` tells ansible to feed **whatever** task result inside a variable. In your second example:

- The first task runs fine on "Amazon" and registers its successful result in `ucheck` (including an `rc` field from the `shell` module).
- Then the next task is skipped for "Centos or Redhat" and overrides `ucheck` with a skipped task result. Since this second result only contains info about the skipped task (debug for yourself to see the exact full content), it does not contain any info about running the `shell` module hence not any `rc` attribute.

This definitely explains your error message. You need to debug in each situation or use different variables. Here is a possible solution:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ target }}"

  tasks:

    - name: uptime al2
      shell: uname -r
      changed_when: true
      ignore_errors: true
      register: ucheck
      when: ansible_distribution == 'Amazon'

    - debug:
        msg: "RC is {{ ucheck.rc }}"
      when: ucheck is not skipped

    - name: uptime centos
      shell: uname -r
      changed_when: true
      ignore_errors: true
      register: ucheck
      when: ansible_distribution == 'CentOS' or ansible_distribution == 'RedHat'

    - debug:
        msg: "RC is {{ ucheck.rc }}"
      when: ucheck is not skipped
```

Comment: `2021-06-24 15:59:22Z` `2021-06-24 15:59:35Z` heh, that's amazing -- great minds ... :-D

Comment: @mdaniel: "Les grands esprits se rencontrent" ;) Even with time shift.

Answer (score 2):

Ansible *always* processes the `register:` task keyword, even if skipped, because it allows one to later test `when: my_var is skipped` which wouldn't be possible without registration

So, you'll need a unique variable for each one of those cases. But, thankfully you don't need `thing1 is not skipped and thing1.rc == 0` because there is the more helpful [`is failed`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results) (or `is succeeded`) jinja2 tests that do the right thing